# Получить ответ в string okhttp3

Tags: java, android, okhttp

Пытаюсь получить ответ от сервера:

```
try {
        str = client.newCall(new Request.Builder().url(str).build()).execute().body().string();
        Log.d(TAG, str);
        return str;
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG,e.toString());
        return "ERR";
    }
```

Но получаю `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начиная с `API=14` делать запросы в сеть в основном потоке - запрещено и система выкидывает вам такую ошибку.

В случае `OkHttp` вам надо делать асинхронный вызов:

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
  @Override public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  @Override public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
      String serverResponseAsString = response.body().string();
      System.out.println(serverResponseAsString);
    }
  }
});
```